# Overlaying a matrix of intensities over the world map

Tags: openlayers

I have a matrix that covers the whole world, with a different intensity per coordinate. I want to overlay these intensities on top of the world map.

I was originally using a vector layer, dividing he world coordinates by the resolution of this matrix, and creating polygons with a colour that depends on the value of this location in the matrix of intensities. When migrating it to OpenLayers 3, I have been suggested to change the implementation to using an ol.source.Raster instead.

The [samples](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/raster.html) on [ol.source.Raster](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Raster.html) are limited, so I am having trouble understanding the steps required. I understand I would create the ol.source.Raster more or less like:

```
var raster = new ol.source.Raster({
    sources: [sourceMatrix],
    operation: function(pixels, data) {
        return pixels[0];
    }
});
```

Where sourceMatrix has to be an ol.source.Source, so I could maybe create an ol.source.ImageCanvas with the data of the input matrix.

Would that be the right approach? Is there any other sample on ol.source.Source that would fit my use case better?

Comment: If the data is of XYZ(lon,lat,intensity) format,you can convert it to a raster using GDAL with gdal_translate ascii_intensity.xyz  raster_intesity.tif.Perhaps you can use this as source raster.

Comment: The data is dynamic; I receive it from an external source via AJAX.